# Is $(X,T)$ is door space?

Tags: general-topology

A topological space $(X, T)$ is said to be a door space if every subset of $X$ is either an open set or a closed set (or both).

Is the following given statement is true/false ?

If$ X$ is an infinite set and $T$ is the finite-closed topology, then $(X, T)$ is a door space.

My attempt :

I thinks  this statement is True  take  $X=\Bbb N$, there are plenty of open sets which are  the whole thing or the empty set, such as $\{1,2, 3,4,5,\ldots, n+1,\ldots\}$

Comment: Of "open sets which are the whole thing or the empty set", there are two, not "plenty".

Comment: okss sorry@Gae.S.

Comment: “either an open set or a closed set (or both)”—as opposed to neither, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using $X=\Bbb{N}$, and taking $U=\{1,3,5,7,\ldots\}$, i.e. the odd numbers. Then this set is not open, because its complement is not finite, and it is not closed because it is not finite. So, if I understood your definition correctly, this is not a door space.

Comment: thanks u alekos Robotis  Got it

Comment: When  I was in a class, the tutor wrote "If x is not open then x is closed" and said "This is true if x is a door." Countless other tutors must have done this, especially if they had to mark the homework,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,+1

Answer (score 3):

If $X$ is infinite, one can take $A$ and $B$ to be disjoint infinite subsets of $X$ such that $X=A\stackrel{\cdot}{\cup} B$. Thus, $A$ and $B$ are neither open nor closed in $X$. This shows that $X$, with the finite-closed topology, is not a door space.